# Items api '/api/v1/items?resourceType=app' return empty

Tags: qliksense

I'm following the tutorial  on this link https://qlik.dev/embed/integrate-web-apps/build-a-simple-web-app

Everything works fine. I can get the user information. I can get the CRSF TOKEN. all as expected on the tutorial.

However, when I try to get the apps, I always get an empty list even though it was supposed to have some apps on the response.

Things I have checked:

- The user is authenticated
- If I put the address  https://your-tenant.us.qlikcloud.com/api/v1/items?resourceType=app I get the apps
- Using the fetch on cors mode returns only the apps I created with the user but calling it directly on the browser returns more entries.

The same request, configured as the tutorial, under the cors returns distinct results. Why?

Comment: An update:

- Using the fetch on cors mode returns only the apps I created with the user but calling it directly on the browser returns more results.